# Create comma separated group list from rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract a comma separated list from the following:

[image]

Return should gives something like

1 : Route#1, Route#2

2 : Route#3, Route#4

3 : Route#5

4 : Route#6

I'm struggling with the STUFF function. So far I have:`SELECT STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ';' + T4.[Outbound Trucks] FROM #TEMP4 T4 FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'') AS MasterRoutes`

Result gives me
[image]

any help would be really appreciated.

thanks a lof for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sql server is 2017 or more :

```
SELECT dorno, STRING_AGG ([Outbound Trucks], ',') as CSV
FROM #TEMP4
GROUP BY dorno
```

Explanation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In you case you can eliminate doublon to like this:

```
with tmp as (
select distinct dorno, [Outbound Trucks] Truck from #TEMP4
)
SELECT dorno, STRING_AGG (Truck, ',') as CSV
FROM tmp
GROUP BY dorno
```